# Asymptotic distribution of $(\bar{Y}_n - E(|X_1|)) / \bar{X}_n$

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

> Let $(X_n)$ be i.i.d double exponential random variables, with PDF $\frac1{2a}e^{-|x|/a}$, thus $E(X_n) = 0$, $E(|X_n|) = a$ and $V(X_n)=2a^2$. Consider the sample means $$\bar{X}_n=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i\qquad\bar{Y}_n=\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|X_i|.$$ One is interested in the asymptotic distribution of $$R_n=\frac{\bar{Y}_n - a}{\bar{X}_n}.$$

I want to use the delta method, but the expectation of $\bar{X}_n$ is $0$, which causes the problem when dividing.

Any other idea?

Comment: By the multidimensional central limit theorem, the vector $\sqrt{n}\cdot\left(\bar X,\bar Y-a\right)$ converges to a centered normal vector $(Z,T)$ with known covariance matrix hence $(\bar Y-a)/\bar X$ converges in distribution to $T/Z$. The variances are $\mathrm{var}(Z)=\mathrm{var}(X_1)=E(X_1^2)$ and $\mathrm{var}(T)=\mathrm{var}(|X_1|)=E(X_1^2)-E(|X_1|)^2$ and the covariance is $\mathrm{cov}(Z,T)=\mathrm{cov}(X_1,|X_1|)=E(X_1|X_1|)-E(X_1)E(|X_1|)=0$ hence $(Z,T)$ is independent. Can you finish?

Comment: Got it, I made a mistake at the cov which made it dependent. Thanks.